# WooCommerce Increase stock for a new order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

I added a new order status to check for "change orders".
I want to increase the stock level by using this order status as the customer will send the product back to me. It will follow a path like the canceled order status, but only the name of the order status will be "change". When the order status is "change", it will increase the stock of the variation product by the quantity of products in the order.

Ex:
A102-L stock: 12,
A108-M stock: 15.

Stock codes and quantities of the products in the order:
Order ID: 1234
order products:
A102-L -> 1 pc
A108-M -> 2 pcs

Suppose an order is created with these products. When I make the Woocommerce order status "processing" it updates the stock levels to 11 for A102-L and 13 for A108-M. When I make this order status "change" , I want to update the stock levels as 12(11+1) for A102-L and 15(13+2) for A108-M.

I added the new order status name but I couldn't do the stock increase part. How can I do it?

Comment: _"I added a new order status"_, _"I added the new order status name"_ - how? through a plugin? with which code? - Your question contains a description of what you have done and want to do. What it does not contain, however, is [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ni-woocommerce-custom-order-status/ I added the new order status using this plugin. But that just adds in the name. I can't check the product stocks in the order with this plugin. For this, I researched that it can be done with php codes. I tried some codes but it didn't work. Since I don't know php, I couldn't do it exactly. If there is a sample php code block I will struggle to do what I want. However, there are those who use order status the way I want, and if there is, I opened a topic in this way to quickly solve it. I'm a new member :))

Answer (score 0):

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', $this->get_id(), $status_transition['from'], $status_transition['to'], $this );
```

This hook is triggered whenever an order status changes.

So to increase stock level of items in an order when the order status updated to 'change' can be done like below. Add the code into active theme functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'custom_woocommerce_order_status_changed', 10, 4);

function custom_woocommerce_order_status_changed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order) {
        if ('change' == $new_status) {
            wc_increase_stock_levels($order);
        }
    }
```